# Random Does Not Seem To Be Working in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am creating a "Position" table with which to use as a lookup. Each time I look up a value in the position table, I want to use that value as I create/insert sample data into a statistics table. My insert works but for the Position field, I only get the value "First Base" inserted into each row 75 times. Can someone show me what I am doing wrong so I can get the other positions to get inserted (or at least some of them randomly of course)? The line in question is marked with ***.

```
CREATE TABLE Position 
(
  PositionId INT NOT NULL 
, Position VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL 
);
   
Insert into POSITION (POSITIONID,POSITION) values (2,'Catcher');
Insert into POSITION (POSITIONID,POSITION) values (3,'First Base');
Insert into POSITION (POSITIONID,POSITION) values (4,'Second Base');
Insert into POSITION (POSITIONID,POSITION) values (5,'Third Base');
Insert into POSITION (POSITIONID,POSITION) values (6,'Shortstop');
Insert into POSITION (POSITIONID,POSITION) values (7,'Left Field');
Insert into POSITION (POSITIONID,POSITION) values (8,'Center Field');
Insert into POSITION (POSITIONID,POSITION) values (9,'Right Field');

CREATE TABLE SEASON_STATISTICS 
(
  SEASON_STATISTICSID INT NOT NULL 
, EMPLOYEEID INT NOT NULL 
, GAMES INT NOT NULL 
, YEAR INT NOT NULL 
, ATBATS INT DEFAULT 0 
, HITS INT DEFAULT 0 
, HR INT DEFAULT 0 
, RBI INT DEFAULT 0 
, AVG NUMBER DEFAULT 0 
, POSITION VARCHAR2(20) 
, TEAMID INT 
, LEAGUE VARCHAR2(20) 
, ERA NUMBER 
, HITSALLOWED INT 
, INNINGSPITCHED NUMBER
, Walks Number
, "DATE_STATS_MODIFIED" DATE
);

CREATE SEQUENCE SEASON_STATS_SEQ  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE  NOKEEP  NOSCALE  GLOBAL;

INSERT INTO SEASON_STATISTICS (Season_StatisticsId, EMPLOYEEID, GAMES, YEAR, ATBATS, HITS, HR, RBI, AVG, POSITION, TEAMID, LEAGUE) 
SELECT SEASON_STATS_SEQ.nextval, 
    ROUND(dbms_random.value(1, 9)), -- EmployeeId
    ROUND(dbms_random.value(1, 56)), -- Games
    '2022', 
    ROUND(dbms_random.value(50, 175)), -- At Bats
    ROUND(dbms_random.value(15, 45)),   -- Hits 
    ROUND(dbms_random.value(1, 17)),    -- HR
    ROUND(dbms_random.value(1, 64)),    -- RBI
    ROUND(dbms_random.value(100, 350)) / 1000,                             -- Avg
        ***(SELECT Position FROM Position WHERE PositionId = (SELECT ROUND(dbms_random.value(2, 9)) FROM Dual)), 
    ROUND(dbms_random.value(1, 10)), 
    'NL'
    FROM DUAL
connect by level <= 75;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of your subquery is being cached and reused. Ideally, you would not store the lookup value of your `POSITION` in your `SEASON_STATISTICS` table - you would store the `POSITIONID` as a foreign key and join to the `POSITION` table when you needed the text value. This would allow you call the `DBMS_RANDOM` function directly - forcing the re-execution and avoiding cached values.

Try something more like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Position 
(
  PositionId INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL 
, Position VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL 
);
   
Insert into POSITION (POSITIONID,POSITION) values (2,'Catcher');
Insert into POSITION (POSITIONID,POSITION) values (3,'First Base');
Insert into POSITION (POSITIONID,POSITION) values (4,'Second Base');
Insert into POSITION (POSITIONID,POSITION) values (5,'Third Base');
Insert into POSITION (POSITIONID,POSITION) values (6,'Shortstop');
Insert into POSITION (POSITIONID,POSITION) values (7,'Left Field');
Insert into POSITION (POSITIONID,POSITION) values (8,'Center Field');
Insert into POSITION (POSITIONID,POSITION) values (9,'Right Field');

CREATE TABLE SEASON_STATISTICS 
(
  SEASON_STATISTICSID INT NOT NULL 
, EMPLOYEEID INT NOT NULL 
, GAMES INT NOT NULL 
, YEAR INT NOT NULL 
, ATBATS INT DEFAULT 0 
, HITS INT DEFAULT 0 
, HR INT DEFAULT 0 
, RBI INT DEFAULT 0 
, AVG NUMBER DEFAULT 0 
, POSITIONID INT REFERENCES position(positionid)
, TEAMID INT 
, LEAGUE VARCHAR2(20) 
, ERA NUMBER 
, HITSALLOWED INT 
, INNINGSPITCHED NUMBER
, Walks Number
, DATE_STATS_MODIFIED DATE
);

CREATE SEQUENCE SEASON_STATS_SEQ  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE  NOKEEP  NOSCALE  GLOBAL;

INSERT INTO SEASON_STATISTICS (Season_StatisticsId, EMPLOYEEID, GAMES, YEAR, ATBATS, HITS, HR, RBI, AVG, POSITIONID, TEAMID, LEAGUE) 
SELECT SEASON_STATS_SEQ.nextval,   
    ROUND(dbms_random.value(1, 9)), -- EmployeeId
    ROUND(dbms_random.value(1, 56)), -- Games
    '2022', 
    ROUND(dbms_random.value(50, 175)), -- At Bats
    ROUND(dbms_random.value(15, 45)),   -- Hits 
    ROUND(dbms_random.value(1, 17)),    -- HR
    ROUND(dbms_random.value(1, 64)),    -- RBI
    ROUND(dbms_random.value(100, 350)) / 1000,   -- Avg
    ROUND(dbms_random.value(2, 9)), -- Position 
    ROUND(dbms_random.value(1, 10)), 
    'NL'
    FROM DUAL
connect by level <= 75;

commit;
```

You should see output like this:

```
Table POSITION created.


1 row inserted.


1 row inserted.


1 row inserted.


1 row inserted.


1 row inserted.


1 row inserted.


1 row inserted.


1 row inserted.


Table SEASON_STATISTICS created.


Sequence SEASON_STATS_SEQ created.


75 rows inserted.


Commit complete.
```

Then query your tables together, like this:

```
select
  s.SEASON_STATISTICSID 
, s.EMPLOYEEID 
, s.GAMES 
, s.YEAR 
, s.ATBATS 
, s.HITS 
, s.HR 
, s.RBI 
, s.AVG 
, p.POSITION 
, s.TEAMID 
, s.LEAGUE 
, s.ERA 
, s.HITSALLOWED 
, s.INNINGSPITCHED 
, s.Walks 
, s.DATE_STATS_MODIFIED 
from season_statistics s
join position p on (p.positionid = s.positionid);
```

and you should see this:

```
SEASON_STATISTICSID EMPLOYEEID      GAMES       YEAR     ATBATS       HITS         HR        RBI        AVG POSITION                           TEAMID LEAGUE                      ERA HITSALLOWED INNINGSPITCHED      WALKS DATE_STAT
------------------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ------------------------------ ---------- -------------------- ---------- ----------- -------------- ---------- ---------
                  1          5         26       2022         78         36         12         18       .111 Center Field                            4 NL                                                                             
                  2          7         25       2022         76         43          6         42       .263 First Base                              4 NL                                                                             
                  3          9         18       2022         72         34          8         43       .281 Second Base                             9 NL                                                                             
                  4          2         20       2022        165         18          7         24       .128 Shortstop                               8 NL                                                                             
                  5          6         29       2022        164         29          3         58       .127 Right Field                             4 NL                                                                             
                  6          4         41       2022        100         37         10         28       .277 Left Field                              9 NL                                                                             
                  7          2         15       2022        140         20         14          5       .147 First Base                              3 NL                                                                             
                  8          7         46       2022        171         44         10         51       .241 First Base                              4 NL                                                                             
                  9          3          5       2022         80         32         16         12       .116 Third Base                              9 NL                                                                             
                 10          4         46       2022         57         38          5         42        .12 Second Base                             4 NL
```